# Game Center Not Showing All Items

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I have just started integrating Game Center into my app and so far it has been fine.

I created a leaderboard which works perfectly, and 1 achievement which worked.

It came time to update game centre with all the other information and I have gone onto iTunes Connect and added 9 other achievements as well as adding my app icon into Game Center.

However, when I go into Game Center it appears as it did before I did those updates and I can't seem to get them to show, this includes my app icon, there is nothing there, just the leaderboard which is still updating fine, and the first achievement I made. The other 9 and my icon are nowhere to be seen?

Has anyone had this problem or know any fixes? Id like to be able to test the other achievements before submitting for approval.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting your update (in iTunes Connect) you need to make sure that you are checking off to add each of the new achievements.

**Just because you create them does not mean you apply them to the update!**